# Is "Breaking In" canceled or not?

Tags: breaking-in

I recently started watching a show called "[Breaking In](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1630574/)". I have found multiple different articles, some claiming it was cancelled, then renewed, and then others claiming that it was cancelled again.

Can someone please set the record straight? As of the current date, what is the official status of the show? Also, can someone please explain what happened with the whole "cancelling/un-cancelling" situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I’m afraid [*Breaking In*](http://thefutoncritic.com/showatch/breaking-in/) is officially canceled. Just like [*I Hate My Teenage Daughter*](http://thefutoncritic.com/showatch/i-hate-my-teenage-daughter/), it got a second chance (to be aired during breaks/summer) thanks to FOX’s weak list of filler shows. Unfortunately both shows performed poorly (despite *Breaking In* trying to shake things up in season two), and were not renewed for a third/second season.

As a side-note, Odette Yustman’s timely departure of *Breaking In* for *House* is interesting because both shows were cancelled by FOX, so she was no better off in either, though her presence (or lack thereof) may be conjectured to have had an effect on the fate of the shows.